# How to ER Diagram MYSQL

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, erd

I'm trying to create simple library database in mysql. I have 5 tables students, entry, book, typebook, author. When I was trying to make er diagram with mysql reverse engineer my tables doesn't have any relationships on er diagram. But almost every databases have relationships on er diagram in the internet. What am i doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
CREATE TABLE student(
`stuNo` INT NOT NULL,
`stuname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`stusurname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`class` INT NULL,
`age` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`stuNo`));

 CREATE TABLE entry(
`stuNo` INT NOT NULL,
`entryno` INT NOT NULL,
`bookno` INT NOT NULL,
`borrowdate` DATE NULL,
`returndate` DATE NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`bookno`));

 CREATE TABLE book(
`bookno` INT NOT NULL,
`bookname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `authorno` INT NOT NULL,
`typeno` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (authorno , typeno));

 CREATE TABLE  typebook (
`typeno` INT NOT NULL,
`typename` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`typeno`));

 CREATE TABLE author(
`authorno` INT NOT NULL,
`authorname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`autorname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`authorno`));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to switch the order of the CREATE TABLE

What changes is the order you have to insert data.
For example

If you want to INSERT a book , you first have to insert  the typebook and author, that corresponds to the book and so on.

```
CREATE TABLE student(
`stuNo` INT NOT NULL,
`stuname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`stusurname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`class` INT NULL,
`age` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`stuNo`));

 CREATE TABLE  typebook (
`typeno` INT NOT NULL,
`typename` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`typeno`));

 CREATE TABLE author(
`authorno` INT NOT NULL,
`authorname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`autorname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`authorno`));

CREATE TABLE book(
`bookno` INT NOT NULL,
`bookname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `authorno` INT NOT NULL,
`typeno` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (authorno , typeno),
INDEX(bookno),
FOREIGN KEY (typeno)
        REFERENCES typebook(typeno),
FOREIGN KEY (authorno)
        REFERENCES author(authorno));

 CREATE TABLE entry(
`stuNo` INT NOT NULL,
`entryno` INT NOT NULL,
`bookno` INT NOT NULL,
`borrowdate` DATE NULL,
`returndate` DATE NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`bookno`),
FOREIGN KEY (stuNo)
        REFERENCES student(stuNo),
FOREIGN KEY (bookno)
        REFERENCES book(bookno)
        );
```

Results in
[image]

Comment: Im kind of beginner. Sorry for that. I did understand why we change order of tables. And  I guess I can do that relationships with my own on diagram manager  without using code like foreign keys. I have one more question In the code  authorno , typeno on table book and bookno on entry table are primary keys. But They don't look like primary key on diagram.. I don't understand why?

Comment: You structure is a bit off, promary key should be in book booid  and authorno , typeno should be an indey or unique constarint, bus as you get further into developing the software there will be soe mot indexes and another structure, i only build a sensible structure wihout changing too much

Comment: i have seen, but ,mysql has as relationship the foreign keys concept, with that you define how two table are linked, and you can also define what to do when the entry is updated (for example the name is  the foreign key and when it is updated you want also every linked table to shgow the new name. So if you wantvthat lines between your tables ion mysql you have to define foreign keys, which are in your case the columns wuth the same names(which is btw also not a god idea)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your tables do not have any `FOREIGN KEYS` set. MySQL has no idea that the `authorno` column from one table should be linked to the `authorno` column from another table. So no relationship links are generated.

To generate the relationship links to your ER diagram, you have to use `FOREIGN KEY` entries in your `CREATE TABLE` query to specify which column from one table is referencing a column from a different table:

```
CREATE TABLE author(
    `authorno` INT NOT NULL,
    `authorname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `autorname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`authorno`)
);

CREATE TABLE book(
    `bookno` INT NOT NULL,
    `bookname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `authorno` INT NOT NULL,
    `typeno` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (bookno),
    FOREIGN KEY (authorno) REFERENCES author(authorno)
);
```

With the added [`FOREIGN KEY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html#create-table-indexes-keys) entries MySQL now knows that the `authorno` column in `book` must reference a value from the `authorno` column of the `author` table. When generating the ER diagram you should get the lines between the tables to see the relationship.